# How can I enable and hide [list, button, images,..etc ]by using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

**so this is the component:**

```
<ReusedHeader
  H1headerGray="text... "
  H2headerRed="text2 ! "
  pheader="p1"
  getStarted="button text1"
  hrefab="button url 1"
  whatWeDo="button text2"
  hrefbb="button url 2"
  imageSrc="image url"
/>;
```

the list in the component :

```
<li className=" hover:ring active:ring-4 w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-700 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10">
  {getStarted}
</li>
```

And this component I will use in many places; in some places, I want the component without buttons;

### how can I enable and disable buttons if possible?

Comment: Where is your button ?

Comment: i get this component from the tailwind component as it is, so i guess that li can do the same thing button do because i see the results and it is no different

Comment: i guess it's a general question: How can I enable and hide [list, button, images,..etc ]by using props

Comment: You can do it by adding a condition on onClick handler , if props.disabled == true then on don't do anything.

Comment: is this condition going to hide the button ?

Comment: No, just change its color to gray ( for example) to make the user feels that it's not clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the needed props and handle the logic within the component

```
const ReusedHeader = ({buttonsEnabled=true}) => {
    if(buttonsEnabled){ // return something }
    else { // return something else }
}
```

Or modify the onClick if you want the same markup without onClick functionality.

```
onClick={buttonsEnabled? onClick : undefined}
```